# This package is superseded by one or more higher-ranked packages

Tags: windows-store-apps

I am trying to update my app in the windows store with a new version.  I am getting the error message in the UI:

> This package is superseded by one or more higher-ranked packages.

The version number of the new binary is higher than the existing one. Here is what the version numbers look like in the store UI:
[image]

How can I raise the rank of the new version so that the store accepts it?  What are the elements to package rank?  I searched online for this but could not find the answer.
Thanks.

Comment: What happens when increasing the minor version?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A day after first having the problem, I submitted a package numbered 2.0.6, which I had tried yesterday, and it went right in.

I tried to delete the original submission as suggested above, before trying submitting 2.0.6, but couldn't find a delete button.  Maybe by opening the older one up in the UI I made the UI realize it was older.  dunno.